# Android how to keep static data on application relaunch?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am having an abstract class having all static objects and function to store some globel data of the application during the execution session.

All data reset to null once I relaunch the application in ICS and above version with Systems's setting ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES is set as true.

Whats the better way to mainitan data on application relaunch?

Regards,

Android IT

**Editing my question:
I know that Sharepreference can be a better option but I dont want to store data for multiple sessions of the application and data I am storing is huge.
Regards,
Android 
IT**

Answer (score 1):

Each Android app is running in a dependent process. When an app become background and system need memory, the app's process may be killed by system. In this situation, when app relaunch,  static objects will lost.

I think use SharedPreference to maintain data is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data using `SharedPreferences`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

Store the data on the local storage would seem appropriate: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data local using a XML file. You can read the XML File on startup with a DOM Reader

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-android/

If you have lots of data you can use a SQLite Database

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 0):

If there are not too much data you can keep them in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

You access them with [PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29)

Answer (score 0):

Once application exit or destroy that will remove all data . if you want to access after relaunch you should save your data as per your requirement . like local or web. its deepen you. right now you can store data in preference so it will useful after relaunch the application.
I think this is better for you : [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)